# How to write a transfer matrix for N layers?

Tags: python, matrix, matrix-multiplication, transfer

We have the matrices G_r and P_r, where r is an index (integer, from 0 to m) meaning one of the N layers of an experimental setup, while n and \delta are variables to be fixed (\delta=n\omega_r (x_(r+1)-x_r), where x represent a position coordinate), defined as in picture; [The starting matrices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gxF1c.png)

Their product leads to the Transfer matrix T defined as in the other picture. [The product matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MQy70.png)

So how can we numerically calculate (Python 3, whole code) the following product of the matrices, for an arbitrary value for m? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wpbjr.png)

I tried with a cycle for but the code, compiled online, does not run (there are errors also in definig the quantities).

```
import numpy as np
import math
int (n) int (r) float (δ)
G_r = 1/(2 * n_(r+1)) [[n_(r+1)+n_r,n_(r+1)-n_r],
[n_(r+1)-n_r, n_(r+1)+n_r]]
P_r=[[e**(iδ_r), 0],[0, e**(-iδ_r) ]]
T=G_r*P_r
for r in range (0, m):
T*=r
print ("Insert value for r:", r)
print (G_r)
print (P_r)
print (T)
```

I should modify the code in order to be able to set the values for each one of the, float value, n_r (e.g., n_0=1, n_1=4.3, n_2=1 and so on, until to n_(m-1)), or something like

```
print ("Insert value for n_0:", n_0)
print ("Insert value for n_1:", n_1)
```

Comment: "I tried with a cycle for but the code, compiled online, does not run (I think there are errors also in definig the quantities)." -> please add this code to your question!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: OK, so your code has quite a lot to unpack. For example, you import `numpy` and `math`, but never use them, the first line after the import does nothing and the rest seems like you are trying to use python a bit like latex.  Anyway, I don't think you need `math` anyway, but I would start reading a bit of the [numpy documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/1.25/) which is the way to go when dealing with multi-dimensional array. It should have the functions you need, like matrix multiplications, exponential functions and so on. Hope this gets you started :)